# Get Notification Whenever MySQL table is updated in PHP without any refresh and without much Load on the Server

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I am developing a card game.
The Logic is 1st player waits till any player joins.
When 2nd player comes to that page, an update in database is made and Player 1 will get a notification that Player 2 has joined without refreshing the page.
I have searched a tons of **jquery and ajax** but none helped me. Please Someone help me as i am stuck in the middle of nowhere. Thanks.

Comment: Ajax seems great for your problem, what are you having problems with?

Comment: You are looking for 'LONG POLLING' which means a ajax request is sent to the server and the server continuously checks for the database change and send the output once the change occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do long polling in ajax

[How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)

And possibly use memcache rather then database, especially if you are polling alot to keep track of how many players have joined, etc, but I will leave that decision up to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Are there any definitive guide to implement these as I am a novice user of jquery and ajax

Answer (score 0):

use `$.post` in jquery for get data without page refreshing.

```
$.post("page.php",{"act":1},function(data){
    $("#id").html(data);
});
```

in `page.php` write your query

Comment: But I need to get the notification only when there is a change in database table.. like when a new insert is done then only I want to get a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Id recommend websockets. Search for any simple chat tutorial which should include all the necessary features you need for your game.

Comment: HTML5 web socket is not supported by Internet Explorer

Comment: Depends on which Version you are using